# MongoEngine vs MongoKit for Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Have you used MongoEngine or MongoKit with Django? Which one do you prefer?

Background:

I'm developing a new site and have experience with *normal* Django development but for the kind of data I'll be using the MongoDB will be better suited than a SQL database.

I'm using Python 2.7 and can compile/install anything on my host so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

mongoengine will be more django like in how you handle your models. That is why i choose it for my projects

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes mongoengine is more simular to django db model style as mongokit but mongokit represent more the style and layout of your raw mongodb model. +1 for MongoKit

If you able to choice beside this two libs than I would take [django-mongodb-engine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mongodb-engine/) because it is special builded for django and the admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: MongoEngine!

I've had the pleasure to work many times both with MongoKit and MongoEngine on complex projects.

I'll start from the end: MongoKit project on GitHub is dead. When choosing the right tool, always remember that working with well maintained project is a huge difference. There are more features, less bugs and always someone to help you with problems.

If you do very simple stuff with MongoKit you'll be fine. But when using more features, I found more and more bugs. Actually I also submitted fixes and there were no one to accept them. On the other hand, MongoEngine community is super professional and a live.

After getting used to MongoEngine syntax I enjoy every bit of it :)

Answer (score 0):

You say you have experience with

> normal Django development

Then why don't you continue to use the usual Django ORM and connect it to MongoDB using a [connector](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)?

**[Djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/)**: The strategy is to translate Django SQL query syntax generated by the Django ORM into pymongo commands. Djongo translates every SQL query string into a mongoDB query document.

If you want to manipulate MongoDB using Django Admin, fire it up:

`manage.py runserver`

Goto: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Manipulate your MongoDB embedded models as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

There is an article on [Using Django with MongoDB](https://medium.com/@SiddyZen/using-django-with-mongodb-by-adding-just-one-line-of-code-c386a298e179) by adding just one line of code, if you are looking for more information. Otherwise, you can jump directly into the [djongo documentation](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) and start using it.